# how to download multiple files using axel

Tags: linux

I have a 5 files (e.g. a.zip, b.zip. c.zip etc..) that I would like to download using [Axel](http://axel.alioth.debian.org/). As documentation is limited, does anyone know the right command?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if Axel already has a function to read a list, but if it doesn't you can use a while loop. Assuming you have a file named 'mylinks.txt' with your URLs separated by a return, ie

http://www.example.com/1.jpg

http://www.example.com/2.mp3

http://www.example.com/bobsparty.avi

Then type in terminal :

```
while read url; do axel $url; done < mylinks.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use axel to download multiple files with one command! You just create a shell script with all of the links and run the script. This one downloads each link one at a time, and pauses for 10 seconds and turns off your computer after all of the links have finished downloading, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash  
axel link1 -a  
axel link2 -a  
axel link3 -a  
sleep 10  
poweroff
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach to download from a file:

```
cat mylinks.txt |xargs -d '\n' -l1  axel -akn 16
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get multiple files with one command, although you can just repeat the command for each file.  The command would be

From multiple URL's

```
axel -o file.ext <url1> <url2> <url3>
```

From a single URL (Multiple connections - x=number of connections)

```
axel -o file.ext -n x <url1>
```

This is an OK(ish) reference
    http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/speed-your-downloads-axel